# How to redirect log file in to a stable folder in Nextflow?

Tags: logging, nextflow

Whenever I run an `nf` file, a log file (`.nextflow.log.x`) appears in the working directory. It causes me uncomfortable, so how to redirect it to a folder such as `my_log` using [`nextflow.config`](https://training.nextflow.io/basic_training/config/#config-syntax) file? I have browsed [Directives page](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#directives) of Nextflow, but I didn't see any directive related to the log file.

Thanks.

This is `hello.nf` for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

params.greeting = 'Hello world!'
greeting_ch = Channel.of(params.greeting)

process SPLITLETTERS {
    input:
    val x

    output:
    path 'chunk_*'

    """
    printf '$x' | split -b 6 - chunk_
    """
}

process CONVERTTOUPPER {
    input:
    path y

    output:
    stdout

    """
    cat $y | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]' 
    """
}

workflow{
    letters_ch = SPLITLETTERS(greeting_ch)
    results_ch = CONVERTTOUPPER(letters_ch.flatten())
    results_ch.view{ it }
}
```

Output:

```
$ ls -a
.           hello.nf         .nextflow.log.2   .nextflow.log.5   work
..         .nextflow.log    .nextflow.log.3    .nextflow.log.6
blockfile  .nextflow        .nextflow.log.1    .nextflow.log.4  .nextflow.log.7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nextflow -log` for this. For example, to save all [execution logs](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/cli.html#execution-logs) to a file called `/var/log/nextflow.log`, use:

```
nextflow -log /var/log/nextflow.log run hello.nf
```

Note that `-log` will override the `NXF_LOG_FILE` environment variable, which does the same thing:

```
NXF_LOG_FILE="/var/log/nextflow.log" nextflow run hello.nf
```

Or using `export`:

```
export NXF_LOG_FILE="/var/log/nextflow.log"
nextflow run hello.nf
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, straight to the point. Can we set path of log file in config file (nextflow.config), though?

Comment: @RossyClair I don't think there's an option for this unfortunately. Nextflow starts logging before any config files are parsed. It's also an option that's not specific to the `run` command (i.e. it can be used with `pull`, `clone`, `list` etc). I updated my answer to mention the `NXF_LOG_FILE` environment variable, which can also be used to set the path to the Nextflow log file. HTH.